# Footer background to fit page. CSS

Tags: html, css

so im currently stuck on my footer of the website i am making. I am not sure as to why the footer background does not fit to the sides and bottom of the page, any help ? Thanks for your time.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgMGvY

```
.footer {
  background-color: #5a5a5a;
  margin-top:30px;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.bottom-footer {
  border-top:1px solid #b2b2b2;
  margin-top:10px;
  padding-top:10px;
  color:#b2b2b2;


}

.footer-nav {
  text-align:right;
  list-style:none;
}

.footer-nav li {
  padding:0px 10px;
  display:inline;
}
```

Your .offer class has padding: 50px set. This is why your footer is not extending to the sides of the browser window. - answered

Comment: Your footer is inside your offer div, and offer has a padding. Pull it out of the offer and make sure your body's padding is set to 0 also?

Comment: Use your browser Developer Tools. `Right Click > Inspect Element`. When you hover over your html in the window you will see borders and outlines where things end/begin. This will help you diagnose things like this. It's what everyone else here used I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.offer` class has `padding: 50px` set. This is why your footer is not extending to the sides of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your footer does not extend to the side is that it was inside another div .offer which has a padding of 50px. Try setting it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your .offer class has padding: 50px set. This is why your footer is not extending to the sides of the browser window. - ANSWERED